# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=1$, there exists a subsequence $\{A_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with $P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_{n_k}\right)>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space. Given a sequence of events $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathcal F$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=1$, there exists a subsequence $\{A_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that
$$P\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_{n_k}\right)>0.$$

**My Proof:** Choose a sequence $\{\varepsilon_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ with $\varepsilon_j=4^{-j-1}>0$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\varepsilon_j=12^{-1}<1$ by the geometric series formula. Next, since $P(A_n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$, we can choose a subsequence $\{A_{n_j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ such that $P(A_{n_j})>1-\varepsilon_j$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. Then
$$P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_{n_j}\right)=1-P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_{n_j}^\complement\right)\geq1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty P\left(A_{n_j}^\complement\right)>1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \varepsilon_j=\frac{11}{12}>0.$$

---

Do you agree with my proof above?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I agree with your proof.